# md-chip can add duplicates if model already contains item

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<md-chips ng-model="myModel" md-autocomplete-snap="true"  md-require-match="autocompleteDemoRequireMatch">
                        <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selected" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in myItems| filter:{name: searchText}" md-item-text="item" placeholder="Search ...">
                            <span md-highlight-text="searchText"> {{item.name}}</span>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                        <md-chip-template>
                            <span>
                                <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong>
                            </span>
                        </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

My model myModel contents are as follows:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Judy Foster"}]
```

and my md-items like so:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Judy Foster"}, {"id":"2","name":"Rudy Foster"}, {"id":"3","name":"Moody Foster"}]
```

What happens is if my myModel has nothing .. it works fine, as it does not allow me to enter duplicates.

When myModel already contains an item that also exist in myItems it allows a duplicate.

Anyone any idea how to prevent the duplication from happening?

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9xyrktwL/

Comment: Are you sure that myModel references one of the elements of the array? My guess is that it contains an object that has the same values as one of the elements of the array, but is not an element of the array.

Comment: @JBNizet  say a user has already selected a name and saved it to some database.. now upon retrieval for modification he gets list of all names including the name that is already added to the database and of course Now it is a different instance of the name .. but I do not want that name to be added again if it already exists...  If that answers your question. I also updated the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question. My question is: are you sure that `myModel === myItems[0]` is true? If not, then myModel is not a duplicate of the first item. It's another object that looks the same, but is not.

Comment: @JBNizet I added jsfiddle.

Comment: And that was just what I expected. The object in myModel is NOT === to the object in myItems, contrary to what you just claimed. It's a **different** object, which has the same fields. It must be the same object. See https://jsfiddle.net/upoamyjy/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your model object and the first item of your items list are not the same, even if it has the same attributes, they are different objects in memory, so try to rewrite your controller to point to the same object, like that:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {


    $scope.myItems = [{"id":"1","name":"Judy Foster"}, {"id":"2","name":"Rudy Foster"}, {"id":"3","name":"Moody Foster"}];
    $scope.myModel = [$scope.myItems[0]];
}]);
```

Comment: In my instance i have to keep them separate... and it needs to be dynamic .. myModel will contain  what is selected from myItems and I want to avoid duplicates if there is already an object inside my myModel.

Comment: If you keep them separated, they will not be the same object, so md-chip will not prevent the object to be duplicated, somehow your application logic needs to instantiate the object just once and point both of your arrays to it.

Comment: This pen has the problem you have, to fix it, selectedVegetables needs to point to an object inside of the vegetables array, like self.selectedVegetables = [self.vegetables[0]];

Comment: If my  $scope.myItems  = ['a', 'a','b']   then how Can I select duplicate value in chip

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this as this is actually the complete answer.

The following code needs to be added for complete solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/5sgeLj6y/

```
$scope.newModel = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myItems.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.myModel.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.myItems[i].id === $scope.myModel[j].id) {
        $scope.newModel[j] = $scope.myItems[i];        
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```